# Namespace is not working properly

Tags: c#

I am getting a error for my namespace that says " the type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) " and have no idea why... i have been trying to figure this one out for hours now... btw i am a newbie with c#

```
using System;
using System.Data; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using portfolioNamespace;  

public partial class DefaultCode : System.Web.UI.Page{

    Portfolio myPortfolio;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //declare
        myPortfolio = new Portfolio();
        populate();
    } 

    private void populate(){
        //populate everything
        populateMenu();
        populateHome();
        populateSamples();
        populateAbout();
    }

    private void populateMenu(){
        //populate the menu
        String[] menu;
        menu = myPortfolio.getMyMenu();

        repLinks.DataSource = menu;
        repLinks.DataBind();
        //populates a hidden text box so i can get an array in javascript 
        for (int i = 0; i<=menu.Length - 1; i++){
            dummy.Value = dummy.Value & menu(i) & "-";
        }
    }

    private void populateHome(){
        //populate home 
        homeRepeater.DataSource = myPortfolio.getHomeInfo;
        homeRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    private void populateSamples(){
        //populate samples
        samplesRepeater.DataSource = myPortfolio.getSamplesInfo;
        samplesRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    private void populateAbout(){
        //populate about
        aboutRepeater.DataSource = myPortfolio.getAboutInfo;
        aboutRepeater.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not actually declaring a namespace anywhere in that code.  You need to wrap your class in a "namespace portfolioNamespace { }" block.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: The issue could be with portfolioNamespace. Check that if you have referenced it.

Comment: portfolioNamespace is from dll or your declared yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Solution Explorer` Right click your `References`, click `Add Reference > Browse`, then find your `dll` file that contains `portfolioNamespace` and add it to your References.

See documentation for more details: [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: shouldn't it just work... i have it up on a server and i have my cs file in my App_Code folder

Comment: No--Selman22 is correct, you need to add the reference.  Adding the reference "loads" a new .dll into the solution.  `using <namespace>` just lets you use the classes in that namespace without having to type in the fully qualified path. As an example, if you want to use `StreamReader`, you have to either declare it as `System.IO.StreamReader` OR you can put `using System.IO;` at the top and then just declare it as a `StreamReader`. BUT, either way, you have to have a reference to the "System" dll.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't created the portfolioNamespace.

You do so by wrapping your code in

```
namespace portfolioNamespace
{
 //your code here
}
```

Have a read through these references, [namespace (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) and [Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which file is getting error.

whatever the class name is giving error put cursor on that and press CTRL + DOT(.) it will suggest you to add the correct name space